Is the sentence "He only understood the question by slowly." grammatically correct?
I feel the need to add "He only understood the question by slowly studying the grammar." or take out the "by" so the sentence becomes "He understood the question slowly."
However, my teacher said "by" is an adjective modifying "question", "slowly" is an adverb modifying "by", so the sentence is fine by itself.
Is my grammar teacher correct?
Thank you very much!

Slowly modifies studying, not understood. He studied the grammar slowly, which made him able to understand the question.

Your teacher is incorrect.

Adjectives in English generally precede the noun they modify, and adverbs generally precede the adjectives that they modify. So it doesn't make sense for "by" to be modifying "question", or "slowly" to be modifying "by". Also, I don't see what "slowly by question" means. A "by question" I supposed could mean "a question not aimed at the central issue", but how would a question be slowly by?
Also, "only" should be next to what it modifies. Putting it before "understood" means that he didn't do anything with the question other than understanding it, which doesn't make sense. So it would have to be "He understood the question only by slowly studying the grammar."

Thank you for your reply!
The teacher said that while one-word adjectives precede the nouns they modify,  adjective phrases or clauses follow the nouns they modify.  For example, I kicked the round ball under the table. Here, "round" is precedes "ball" while "under the table" follows "ball" and here functions as an adjectival phrase.
Following this logic, he wrote "He understood the question by slowly" on the board and said it is fine. I would agree if the sentence had been something like "He put the books in slowly.", but "put in" is a phrasal-verb!

@KwanHui You appear to be mistaking locative complements for modifiers. The predicate frame for put requires two arguments beyond its subject: the object being put somewhere  and the  locative complement describing where it goes. A complement is not modifying anything because it is not an adjunct but rather a core argument to the verb. See 1, 2, 3, and these.

"He understood the question by slowly" isn't 'fine' on its own. "Slowly studying the grammar" explains how he came to understand.

@KwanHui as tchrist said, a phrase that describes the result of an action is treated differently than something that directly describes the noun. For example, in "I painted the wall red", "red" describes the state that my painting results in the wall being. Also, in your example, "put in" is not a phrasal verb. As I understand it, "in" in that case is analyzed as being an adverb modifying "put". It's not a particle creating a new verb.

@Acccumulation You're right. Thank you for pointing it out and helping me learn! I completely missed this distinction.

@tchrist I don't know what "locative complements", "predicate frame", or "adjunct" means. I'll need to read and study your reference to better understand. Thanks for taking the time to explain to me.

@tchrist Is "He only understood the question by slowly." grammatically correct?
This was an example used to teach inversion: "Only by slowly did he understand the question."
My English teacher said "by" is an adjective because it is right after "question" and "slowly" is an adverb modifying "by".
I grew up in the States and the sentence "sounded" incomplete. The teacher was born and raised in Hong Kong. He explained why it is correct. I have to imagine a sentence such as "My mom picked me up quickly(from school)." Thank you again!

@KateBunting I thought so too! Thank you!
